# Is there any way to convert the elastic search field type from lower case to Title case?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, logstash, elk

My elastic search output for one of key field is getting populated in all lowercase like below.

```
   {
"key" : "activatedevice",
"doc_count" : 2
},
```

Is there any way to add mapping to this field so that my output look like this

```
   {
"key" : "ActivateDevice",
"doc_count" : 2
}'
```

Currently I have mapping defined for this key is below

```
"CallingServiceName": {
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "type": "string"
               },
```

Any Suggestion how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing the word boundary for such concatenated strings is quite difficult.

If your strings were space-separated (or had any other splittable pattern), you could use the following aggregation script to turn your `CallingServiceName` to `TitleCase`:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_csn": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
             String toTitleCase(def s){
               def parts = / /.split(s);
               String titleCaseString = "";
               for (def part : parts){
                  titleCaseString = titleCaseString + toProperCase(part);
               }
               return titleCaseString;
            }
            
            String toProperCase(def s) {
                return s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
                           s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
            }
            

            return toTitleCase(doc['CallingServiceName.keyword'].value);
          """
        },
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the field you pass to the `toTitleCase` function will either need to be of type `keyword` or have `fielddata` set to true in the mapping.

Comment: Thanks Joe, followed approach suggested by you and it worked. Accepting your answer.